# Is it possible for Django to act as a Backend Framework for a SAAS and Smartphone App together?

Tags: django, saas

I want to create an SAAS for businesses and release an App for their customers, which can interact with the SAAS in real time.

**Please give your valuable suggestions on how can I achieve this using the best tools if not the ones I mentioned in the question.**

Comment: This question has nothing to do with iOS or Android. Please don't add those tags.

Comment: Infact it has nothing to do with SO. Questions asking about the suggestion of tools, libraries, books etc are out of the scope for SO

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use django as rest server, and consume its endpoints in your mobile app in real time.

I think [Django rest framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) is your way to start.